# Selecting Keys as SelectedItems in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a dictionary bind to ListView and have two columns .It supports multiple selection an an **Ok** button . Now after selecting items from listview i only want the 1st column i.e the keys of dictionary to be saved in a list list1. 
Help needed :)

Here is the back end code :-

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> list1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        list.Add(1, "a");
        list.Add(2, "b");

        lvUsers.ItemsSource = list;
        lvUsers.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
public void getSelectedItem(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    // Here is the part where you get the keys of selected items
    }

}
```

}

The Xaml code :-

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Margin="10,10,10,0" Name="lvUsers" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="column1" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="column2" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="getitem" Click="getSelectedItem" Grid.Row="1" Content="ok" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var keys =  lvUsers.SelectedItems.OfType<KeyValuePair<int, string>>().Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: It gives error stating
"System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.OfType<TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context."

Comment: Fixed that for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using `terms` that are you are not really doing.

`Binding` in `WPF` is using `{Binding}` syntax or `Binding` class. You are just basically setting the `ItemsSource` given a dictionary.

Because you are not following `MVVM` pattern and just doing it behind the code. You can directly populate your `list1`  by using `LINQ`

```
list1 = lvUsers.SelectedItems.OfType<KeyValuePair<int,string>>().Select(x => x.Key.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you just copy my answer, or did we both forget the ()s after KeyValuePair> :D

Comment: Nope, I don't know about your (). But I was missing the `<int,string>`

Comment: What if i want to get only the values in a string separated by ','?

Comment: In your select you can concat the x.Key with "," then x.Value then that'll be your return value to populate the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the key in the Name property :

```
string MyKey = MyListView.SelectedItems[0].Name;
```

It will give you something like :

```
private void MyListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        string MyKey = MyListView.SelectedItems[0].Name;
        //...
    }
}
```